# Rename files in folder according to a list

Tags: python, list, file, rename

I just started learning Python and I can´t find a solution.
I have 2 lists, one with the actual name of files in a folder **l1** and the other with the names the files should get **l2**. The second list is containing out of a part of the first list. I get an error that the system cannot find the file. I want to let the files in the folder **path** get new names which are contained in **l2**

```
path = r"C:\Users\...\gpx"

l1 = os.listdir(path)                    #read in filenames
l1 = [i.split('-', 2)[1] for i in l1]    #creating list with new names out of old filenames
l1 = [x + ext for x in l1]               #adding filename extensions
l2 = os.listdir(path)                    #list with old filenames

os.path.abspath(path)


x = 0
for file_name in l2:
    os.rename(file_name, l1[x])
    x + 1
```

Comment: Please post the full exception that is raised

Comment: In your `for` loop you aren't changing the value of `x`. It should be `x += 1`. You also need to use the full path of the files

Comment: Also, you aren't saving the path string returned by `os.path.abspath(path)`. And what is `dirs`?